# How to change header in Shipping Method of OnePage checkout

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

The header reads "shipping"

I'd like to change the text. Where can I find this?

[image: onepage screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The title *shipping* comes from a translate csv. My guess it's the `Mage_Checkout`.

You can edit it in `app/locale/[your language]/Mage_Checkout.csv` or copy that file to the design folder so you can update Magento later on. 
Optionally you can also use the inline translation tool.

The label comes from the shipping method itself and is defined in the Admin under `system > configuration > shipping methods`

Here you can pick the shipping method that is displayed on frontend and change the *name*

Comment: I know what you're talking about Method Title and Method Name - but that changes the text before the dollar amount. I am looking to change the text above the method identifiers

Comment: Ah right, updated my answer

Comment: I checked Mage_Checkout.csv as well as Mage_Shipping.csv and there wasn't a single sell that read only "Shipping" as displayed on my checkout page.